# State of resolution in positive characteristic?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, ho.history-overview, characteristic-p

Heisuke Hironaka's [coming talk](http://www.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/node/3357) makes me wonder how the state of the work on that theme is. So far, I noticed (but didn't read) these papers:

*Kawanoue, Hiraku*, [**Toward resolution of singularities over a field of positive characteristic. I. Foundation; the language of the idealistic filtration**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2977/prims/1201012043), Publ. Res. Inst. Math. Sci. 43, No. 3, 819-909 (2007). [ZBL1170.14012](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1170.14012).

*Urabe, Tohsuke*, [**New Ideas for Resolution of Singularities in Arbitrary Characteristic**](http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.1083).

Edit: Another recent [talk](http://plone.mat.univie.ac.at/events/2011/tba-17) by Hironaka (in Vienna).

Comment: Since I know some of the people involved, I'd rather not comment, except to point out that some talks from about a year and a half ago are publicly available here
http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kenkyubu/proj08-mori/.


Comment: Deqr Thomas, My view on the question in your comment below: Yes, it would be a bit of a disaster if resolution (and more generally semi-stable reduction) was false in char. p (or in mixed characteristic)! Regards, Matthew

Comment: http://plone.mat.univie.ac.at/events/2011/tba-17 404

Comment: The link for Vienna's talk is broken.

Answer (score 32):

Also, I'd like to point out this paper of Hironaka...

http://www.math.harvard.edu/~hironaka/pRes.pdf

I haven't read the paper, and also I haven't heard anybody talking about it in the last weeks, which I find a little strange given the problem in question... has anybody here gone through the proof?

Comment: @Turbo: the first page says 23 March 2017. But there might have been earlier versions.

Comment: If anyone happen to have read it, please take a look if you can answer my confusion here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/269651/hironakas-proof-of-resolution-of-singularities-in-positive-characteristics

Answer (score 4):

An (or some) additional very recent references on resolution of singularities in positive characteristic:

There is a recent (expository) article by H. Hauser

On the Problem of Resolution of Singularities in Positive Characteristic (Or: A proof we are still waiting for), Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 2010, Vol. 47,1; p.1-30.

Available on [his webpage](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/herwig.hauser/), where one can also find some preprints around this subject. 
For example,

Wild Singularities and Kangaroo Points for the Resolution in Positive Characteristic

Comment: Thanks a lot! (wondering if it would be a catastrophe if such a resolution would not exist?)  

Comment: @Thomas Riepe: You are welcome. Unfortunately I cannot answer your additional question. My knowledge on the subject is not at all well-developed; I just happened to have heard a talk of Hauser in a general context, and subsequently browsed some of his expository writings.   